# Some Mathematica textbooks specialized for use in (nontrivial) algebra?

Tags: algebra, reference-request

So, Mathematica was constructed as a computer algebra system, but most textbooks focus on programming, mathematical problems of secondary school type  or numerically-technical specialization (matrix, integral or ODE computation...)
But there is a textbook specialized for use in, for instance, group theory, commutative & non-commutative algebra, polynomial algebra (include, for instance Gröbner basis) et.c.?

Comment: See https://www.springer.com/la/book/9780387986197 and http://math.ucsd.edu/~ncalg/ . Unfortunately, the documentation on the latter package is not a textbook.

Comment: The book of [Cox/Little/O'Shea](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=yL7yCAAAQBAJ) has a short section on how to use *Mathematica* along with their book, but it is only a short appendix IIRC.

Comment: @J. M. is somewhat okay: Are you serious? Par 1 of Appendix C consists of 7 pages on Maple, Mathematica, and Sage.